# Can't install SQL Server 2019 Developer Edition

Tags: sql-server

The error I get after going through the install process (from a download media approach). Which is logged in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20220610_171401\Summary_AMD5950X-DEV_20220610_171401.txt file.

> Detailed results:
> Feature:                       Database Engine Services
> Status:                        Failed
> Reason for failure:            An error occurred during the setup process of the feature.
> Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
> Component name:                SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
> Component error code:          1639
> Component log file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20220610_171401\sql_engine_core_inst_Cpu64_1.log
> Error description:             Invalid command line argument. Consult the Windows Installer SDK for detailed command line help.
> Error help link:               https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=15.0.4013.40&EvtType=sql_engine_core_inst.msi%400x162A16FE%400x1639

I'm getting an Invalid command line argument?  I'm not running command line, this is all via the downloaded installer from Microsoft's web site [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads).

I did considerable research to try and solve this but still unable to solve it (I'm at the point of wiping my PC and starting over).

When I get the error the Installer points me to the log file located here C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20220610_164557\sql_engine_core_inst_Cpu64_1_Local.log

I review the log contents here:

```
=== Verbose logging started: 6/10/2022  16:48:57  Build type: SHIP UNICODE 5.00.10011.00  Calling process: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Setup Bootstrap\SQL2019\x64\ScenarioEngine.exe ===
MSI (c) (68:20) [16:48:57:399]: Resetting cached policy values
MSI (c) (68:20) [16:48:57:399]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0
MSI (c) (68:20) [16:48:57:399]: ******* RunEngine:
           ******* Product: E:\x64\setup\sql_engine_core_inst.msi
           ******* Action: 
           ******* CommandLine: **********
MSI (c) (68:20) [16:48:57:399]: Client-side and UI is none or basic: Running entire install on the server.
MSI (c) (68:20) [16:48:57:399]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (c) (68:20) [16:48:57:401]: Cloaking enabled.
MSI (c) (68:20) [16:48:57:401]: Attempting to enable all disabled privileges before calling Install on Server
MSI (c) (68:20) [16:48:57:401]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (s) (DC:10) [16:48:57:405]: Running installation inside multi-package transaction E:\x64\setup\sql_engine_core_inst.msi
MSI (s) (DC:10) [16:48:57:405]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (s) (DC:C0) [16:48:57:405]: Resetting cached policy values
MSI (s) (DC:C0) [16:48:57:405]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0
MSI (s) (DC:C0) [16:48:57:405]: ******* RunEngine:
           ******* Product: E:\x64\setup\sql_engine_core_inst.msi
           ******* Action: 
           ******* CommandLine: **********
MSI (s) (DC:C0) [16:48:57:405]: Machine policy value 'TransformsSecure' is 0
MSI (s) (DC:C0) [16:48:57:406]: User policy value 'TransformsAtSource' is 0
MSI (s) (DC:C0) [16:48:57:406]: Machine policy value 'DisableUserInstalls' is 0
MSI (s) (DC:C0) [16:48:57:406]: Specified instance {A60B3D8E-5311-4BF1-AF7A-D1AC15F9152E} via transform :InstID01.mst;:InstName01.mst is already installed. MSINEWINSTANCE requires a new instance that is not installed.
MSI (s) (DC:C0) [16:48:57:406]: MainEngineThread is returning 1639
MSI (s) (DC:10) [16:48:57:407]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (DC:10) [16:48:57:407]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (DC:10) [16:48:57:407]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (s) (DC:10) [16:48:57:407]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (DC:10) [16:48:57:407]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (DC:10) [16:48:57:407]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (c) (68:20) [16:48:57:407]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (c) (68:20) [16:48:57:408]: MainEngineThread is returning 1639
=== Verbose logging stopped: 6/10/2022  16:48:57 ===
```

The error seems to be this:

> Specified instance {A60B3D8E-5311-4BF1-AF7A-D1AC15F9152E} via transform :InstID01.mst;:InstName01.mst is already installed. MSINEWINSTANCE requires a new instance that is not installed.

I google search and found this information [here](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2019/07/30/sql-server-2019-installation-failure-invalid-command-line-argument-consult-the-windows-installer-sdk-for-detailed-command-line-help/).  So I tried cmd line uninstall using:

```
msiexec /x {A60B3D8E-5311-4BF1-AF7A-D1AC15F9152E}
```

When I execute command line I get the following message.

> SQL Server Setup failed to restore the instance id.

So I searched the registry for the GUID and it finds nothing?

I'm stuck, can't install SQL Server 2019 Dev Edition on my PC (Windows 11 PC, AMD CPU, 500GB space, 64GB RAM).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you (or attempt to) go into the Control Panel and try and delete any dependencies? Do you know if this machine ever had any version of SQL Server installed?  Did you run Services.msc, and if so, what did you see that is related to SQL Server?

Comment: @RSax Yes, this PC did have SQL Server installed.  I upgraded to Windows 11 and since the upgrade I was unable to connect to my local instance of SQL Server.  So I attempt an "Add and Remove" programs for all the related SQL server installs and the main database engine one failed to uninstall.  Currently services only shows "SQL Server Browser" and "SQL Server VSS Writer" ... there is no actual SQL Server instance service.